# I want to show a div after pressing on submit button

Tags: javascript, html, popup, mailchimp

I need some help

The "close modal" button that you see in the line below is hidden at load because i want to force users to write their names and emails before accessing the content.

```
<div class="mc-closeModal" data-action="close-mc-modal" data-dojo-attach-point="modalClose" style="">close</div>
```

What i want to do now is to make it appear again after people have entered their names and emails and pressed on the "Subscribe" button.

I've tried this code below in the console and it works. It submits the details and makes the "close" button appear again.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('iframe').contents().find('input.button').click() //this line targets the submit button "Subscribe"
$("#PopupSignupForm_0 > div.mc-modal > div.mc-closeModal").show() //this line makes the "close" button appear again
});
```

The problem is that it doesn't work when i add it in the website though.

**What i want is pretty simple**

When this event happens

```
    $('iframe').contents().find('input.button').click()
```

I want this to execute

```
    $("#PopupSignupForm_0 > div.mc-modal > div.mc-closeModal").show()
```

Comment: is your button inside an iframe?

Comment: Yes, the submit button is inside a frame. My code works perfectly in the console. It submits the details and then it shows the "close" button in the right upper corner. I just don't get why it doesn't work when i paste in my web page.

Comment: but where's the code that binds to the form's subscribe button? the code you have here just clicks a button and shows a div. what do you expect to happen when you run it on document ready?

Comment: $('iframe').contents().find('input.button').click() // this code targets the Subscribe button.

Comment: When people press on the subscribe button, i want this event to happen "$("#PopupSignupForm_0 > div.mc-modal > div.mc-closeModal").show()"

Comment: see explanation of what's wrong in your code and a solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is just two statments one after another. You're not actually binding anything to the click event. If you wanted to use jquery's click you could do something like this:

```
$('iframe').contents().find('input.button').click(function() {
    $("#PopupSignupForm_0 > div.mc-modal > div.mc-closeModal").show()
});
```

But then you have no idea if the user actually filled in the form. Instead you can 
try this:

```
$('#content__formFields').submit(function() {
    var isValid = true;

    // Check if empty of not
    $(this).find('input[type!="hidden"]').each(function() {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            isValid = false;
            //change the element's css here so user knows whats missing
        }
    });
    if (isValid)
        $("#PopupSignupForm_0 > div.mc-modal > div.mc-closeModal").show()
    return isValid
});
```

Comment: I've tried your first solution (the one without validation) some hours ago and it didn't work. That's why i'm pretty baffled.

Comment: "didn't work" isn't very informative. did the event fire? put an alert() inside the function. Anyway it might be related to a same-origin policy since your form is in an iframe

Comment: I'm playing with it in the console with it and it doesn't do anything. The webpage is [link](http://www.aspeagro.com/EN_Program_Abricot.html)

Comment: Wrapping the code into a setTimeout(function) is what solved the problem. The issue was that i was hiding the div with a setTimeout(function) too and it was being executed 1 second after this script. Thank you for the effort.